# Encrypting powershell passwords

Tags: security, encryption, powershell, passwords

I have a powershell script that connects to a MySQL database - Of course this connection needs a password and I would like to encrypt the password in some way, as opposed to storing the password as plain text.

I have looked into the securestring methods, outputting the password to a file, however I don't think they will work because the encrypted password can only be decrypted by the original user, and the script is going to be distributed onto a number of machines across the network.

Any suggestions on any other methods that would be useful?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the script is going to be distributed onto a number of machines across the network then every credentials that your script is going to use will be accessible to those users and there is no way around it.

You can do two things if there are any private per-user data:

1. create a new user account in the database for every user of your program with restrictive permissions allowing them to do only the things that you want them to do and nothing more
2. have a proxy server that would authenticate them and connect to the database in their name (this is how most websites work)

If all of the data is public and read-only then you can either:

1. create a user account in the database for read-only access and use its credential in all of the distributed copies of your program
2. have a proxy server that doesn't authenticate users but connects to the database instead of exposing it to the public

Number 2 of every one of those options is generally recommended for every database with a security history of MySQL, but number 1 of both of those options would be recommended for databases like CouchDB.

Never distribute any credentials with your program that you don't want your users to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this PowerShell Library http://lunaticexperiments.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/powershell-string-encryption-and-gpg/ to encrypt Oracle and Informix passwords.

Here's an example

```
    #Source Encryption Functions
. ./Library-StringCrypto.ps1
#encrypt string using passphrase
$encrypt = Write-EncryptedString $connString "4#&7yaoff"
#Show encrypted string
$encrypt
#Decrypt string
Read-EncryptedString $encrypt "4#&7yaoff"
```

Comment: If you distribute the encrypted version of `$connString` with your application then you have to also distribute the encryption key (`"4#&7yaoff"`) which can be used by anyone to decrypt the `$connString`. You have basically traded a problem of hiding the database password for a problem of hiding the encryption password. And you can't just encrypt that password with another password, with turtles all the way down.

Comment: You could uses GnuPG with Library-StringCrypto instead.

Comment: You could use PGP, you could use AES, you could use any symmetric or asymmetric, block or stream cipher. But eventually you would have to give your application the **key** to decrypt your data, wouldn't you? The strength of the algorithm is irrelevant if you give the user your key in the first place. You could use a Base64 encoding just as well because it gives you no security whatsoever.

Comment: The original question pertained to encrypting passwords which in the real world there is a need to do so. Yes, I agree its better not to have do deal with password encryption and use Windows authentication or whatever proxy method, but in the end you will still need to store a password somewhere securely.

Comment: The original question was asking about encrypting the main database password as a way to make it safe from the users of the script, which is inherently impossible. OK, let's say that you encrypt the database password with the strongest algorithm on Earth. Your script decrypts the database password using a secret key - `"4#&7yaoff"` in your example. What do you do with the key? How do you store it securely so the user of your script can't see it but your script can use it?

Comment: The pass phrase was an example. I do not believe it to be a complete solution, it merely solves the problem of PowerShell securestring methods which only allow a specific user to decrypt using their user key. Agreed it creates other problems.

Comment: OK. I would actually suggest using solutions from both of our answers together, ie. provide separate credentials for every user **and** store them in a way that only allows a specific user to decrypt using their user key. I think your solution is good for user passwords. I was only worried about storing the main database password that way but I might have been not clear enough. I just want to make it clear that your ideas for storing user credentials are very good.

Comment: IANASE, but there is another danger... Even if the user couldn't easily decrypt the password to know it, they still have the script that uses the password to authenticate.  They could then use that authentication to do whatever that account has permissions to do.  Remember, encryption is a way to keep third parties out, not a way to hide information that a user needs.